# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Validation\Validator as array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication

I get the following error in postman while testing the post request for api/register.

"Error: Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Validation\Validator as array in file C:\Users\azzam\laravel-app\azzamnewapi\app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php on line 25"

Here is my AuthController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request) {

    //validation field
        $validUser=Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'=> 'required|string',
            'email'=> 'required|email',
            'password'=> 'required|string',
        ]);
        

    //create user
        $user= User::create([
            'name'=> $validUser['name'],
            'email'=> $validUser['email'],
            'password'=> bcrypt($validUser['password']),
        ]);

    //response
        return response([ 
            'user'=> $user,
            'token'=> $user->createToken('secret')->plainTextToken,
        ], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {

    //user
        $user= User::find(PersonalAccessToken::findToken(explode(' ',$request->header('Authorization'))[1])->tokenable_id);

    //delete token
        $user->tokens()->delete();

    //reponse
        return response([
            'message'=> 'logout success',
        ], 200);
    }

    
}
```

can anyone please tell me where is the mistake, and how to see the $validUser variable? ThankYou.

Comment: Sidenote, you've made a validator, but you never actually check if it passes... You should probably include some kind of check, like `if ($validUser->passes()) { ... }` (or `->fails()`).

Answer (score 0):

`$validUser=Validator::make` is a validator instance.

To validate and get the validated input you can do:

```
$validUser = $request->validate([
    'name'=> 'required|string',
    'email'=> 'required|email',
    'password'=> 'required|string',
]);
```

If you must use a manually created validator instance you can do:

```
$validUser = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'=> 'required|string',
    'email'=> 'required|email',
    'password'=> 'required|string',
])->safe()->all();
```

These should work with Laravel 8+